# Servant cookie minimal example

Tags: haskell, cookies, servant

Can anyone please provide me with a minimal example of cookies with servant-server, wai, warp, etc.?

For example, a cookie with a single field "language" with value "en"

Is there an easy way like happstack-lite `addCookies` and `lookCookieValue`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To write cookies:

```hs
Get '[JSON] (Headers '[Header "Set-Cookie" SetCookie] ...)
```

`SetCookie` has `ToHttpApiData` instance in recent `http-api-data`, so this just works.

And to read cookies I make own `newtype`, as [`Cookies` is a type alias in `cookie`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cookie-0.4.4/docs/Web-Cookie.html#t:Cookies) so we cannot write instance for it directly.

```hs
newtype Cookies' = Cookies' Cookies -- type Cookies = [(BS.ByteString, BS.ByteString)]

instance FromHttpApiData Cookies' where
  parseHeader = return . Cookies' . parseCookies
  parseQueryParam = return . Cookies' . parseCookies . TE.encodeUtf8
```

Comment: Note for readers: then use in API def like `... :> Header Cookies' :> ....`, and add a `Maybe Cookies'` to the handler function.